# How can I change a simple AND filter into an OR filter

Tags: jquery

I use this filter (see code below) into my portfoliosite, but I would like to change the jquery part a bit. Since I'm not experienced with it, I hope I can get some help with this!

I try to explain my intention with the example I used. I would like to show "all short" and "all man" on my portfoliosite. But in this example only the "short man" will stay when I select "short" and "man". Actually this is an AND filter. I would like to change this into an OR filter, to see all short people (including woman) and to see all man (including tall man).

How can I achieve this?

(sorry for my english, it isn't perfect :P)

```
<div id="filter">
    <h2>Gender</h2>
    <ul>
      <li data-filter="men"> Men</li>
      <li data-filter="women"> Women</li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Height</h2>
    <ul>
      <li data-filter="short"> Short</li>
      <li data-filter="tall"> Tall</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="item men short">Men/Short</div>
    <div class="item men tall">Men/Tall</div>
    <div class="item women short">Women/Short</div>
    <div class="item women tall">Women/Tall</div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#filter li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    var gender = $('#filter ul').eq(0).find('.active').data('filter')||'',
        height = $('#filter ul').eq(1).find('.active').data('filter')||'',
        sel = '.item'+(gender!=''?'.'+gender:'', (height!=''?'.'+height:'');
    $(sel).fadeIn(200)
    $('.item').not(sel).fadeOut(200);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: courier;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#filter ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#filter li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#filter li:before {
  content: '◻';
}

#filter li.active:before {
  content: '▣';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have missed a closing `)` and you need to separate the options with a `,` to make it select either:

e.g.

```
sel = (gender!='' ? '.item.' + gender : '') + (height!='' ? ',.item.' + height : '');
```

This should generate a selector like:

```
.item.female,.item.tall
```

Which reads as "select an .item and has .female, *or*, select an .item and has .tall"

There may be a problem with a leading `,` e.g. where no sex is selected, so you may need to take that into account. e,g by removing the leading `,`:

```
if (sel[0] === ','){
    sel = sel.slice(1);
}
```

Another alternative is to use an actual `filter` call, with a boolean function that returns `true` (for items you wish to keep):

```
$('#filter li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    var gender = $('#filter ul').eq(0).find('.active').data('filter')||'',
        height = $('#filter ul').eq(1).find('.active').data('filter')||'';

    var $match = $('.item').filter(function(){
        return (gender && $(this).is('.' + gender)) || (height && $(this).is('.' + height));
    });

    $('.item').not($match).slideUp();
    $match.slideDown();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/7qufp5s6/

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon: Delete all 1 rating users... excellent idea! ;)